# How to bind a ComboBox section to nestled classes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

**Updated to reflect first answer - Still not working as expected**

I have read a number of posts about binding combobox selections and lists, but I have been unable to get my particular setup to work.

I want to select a question set in a listbox. Then, select a question from a second listbox. Finally, select the correct answer from a list of options in a listbox.

The below populates all the lists appropriately but is not saving the selections as expected. It appears to set all the answers to the first value.

**To Reproduce Issue**

Use the below code and try setting the answer to Question Set 1, Question 1 to false. Then, set question set 2, question 1 to yes.

**Project Setup**

I have a form with 2 list boxes and a single combobox. From top to bottom: QuestionSets -> Questions -> Options

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboBinding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="QuestionSetList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,329,0" Height="118" SelectionChanged="QuestionSetList_SelectionChanged" />
        <ListBox x:Name="QuestionList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,143,329,0" Height="118" SelectionChanged="QuestionList_SelectionChanged" />
        <!--<ComboBox Name="AnswerList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,278,329,0" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId, Mode=TwoWay}"/>-->
        <ComboBox Name="AnswerList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,278,329,0" SelectedValuePath="Id"
            ItemsSource="{Binding OptionData}" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My code is as follows

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace ComboBinding
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<QuestionSet> QuestionSetData = new ObservableCollection<QuestionSet>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            QuestionSetData.Add(new QuestionSet { Id = 1, Value = "Question Set 1" });
            QuestionSetData[0].QuestionData.Add(new Question { Id = 1, Value = "1." });
            QuestionSetData[0].QuestionData[0].OptionData.Add(new ComboData { Id = 1, Value = "True" });
            QuestionSetData[0].QuestionData[0].OptionData.Add(new ComboData { Id = 1, Value = "False" });

            QuestionSetData.Add(new QuestionSet { Id = 1, Value = "Question Set 2" });
            QuestionSetData[1].QuestionData.Add(new Question { Id = 1, Value = "1." });
            QuestionSetData[1].QuestionData[0].OptionData.Add(new ComboData { Id = 1, Value = "Yes" });
            QuestionSetData[1].QuestionData[0].OptionData.Add(new ComboData { Id = 1, Value = "No" });
            QuestionSetData[1].QuestionData.Add(new Question { Id = 2, Value = "2." });
            QuestionSetData[1].QuestionData[1].OptionData.Add(new ComboData { Id = 1, Value = "True" });
            QuestionSetData[1].QuestionData[1].OptionData.Add(new ComboData { Id = 1, Value = "False" });

            QuestionSetList.ItemsSource = QuestionSetData;

            QuestionSetList.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
            QuestionSetList.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
        }

        private void QuestionSetList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            QuestionList.ItemsSource = QuestionSetData[QuestionSetList.SelectedIndex].QuestionData;

            QuestionList.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
            QuestionList.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
        }

        private void QuestionList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (QuestionList.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                AnswerList.DataContext = QuestionSetData[QuestionSetList.SelectedIndex].QuestionData[QuestionList.SelectedIndex];

                //AnswerList.ItemsSource = QuestionSetData[QuestionSetList.SelectedIndex].QuestionData[QuestionList.SelectedIndex].OptionData;
                //AnswerList.DataContext = QuestionSetData[QuestionSetList.SelectedIndex].QuestionData[QuestionList.SelectedIndex].OptionData;

                //AnswerList.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
                //AnswerList.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
            }
        }
    }

    public class QuestionSet
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Question> QuestionData = new ObservableCollection<Question>();
    }

    public class Question
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        //Relocated to Question Class
        public int SelectedId { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<ComboData> OptionData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ComboData>();
        //public ObservableCollection<ComboData> OptionData = new ObservableCollection<ComboData>();
    }

    public class ComboData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public string Value { get; set; }
        //public int SelectedId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notice:**

- Your ComboData have currently the same ID. You have to change this.
- Add get and set to Question.OptionData to bind this to the ComboBox.

First you should place your SelectedId property in Question and not in ComboData. Because the Question is the one who knows the selected Answer and not the Answer.

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ComboData> OptionData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ComboData>();
}
```

Now set the DataContext in QuestionList_SelectionChanged

```
   private void QuestionList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
        if (QuestionList.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            AnswerList.DataContext = QuestionSetData[QuestionSetList.SelectedIndex].QuestionData[QuestionList.SelectedIndex];
        }
   }
```

And in the Xaml bind the combobox as following:

```
<ComboBox Name="AnswerList" VerticalAlignment="Top"       
            SelectedValuePath="Id"
            ItemsSource="{Binding OptionData}" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
```

The order is extremely important. First bind the ItemsSource and than the SelectedValue. See also this post on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f7267b68-276e-49f1-8f6e-0e6caeec6e32/databinding-clears-combobox-value-on-datacontext-switch?forum=wpf).

**Edit:** This is also a good explanation for working and binding with ComboBox: [WPF ComboBox and DataBinding.](http://blog.cylewitruk.com/2010/09/wpf-combobox-and-databinding-datacontext-itemssource-displaymemberpath-selecteditem-selectedvalue-selectedvaluepath/)

Comment: I tried the changes you suggested and have updated the code in the question. However, I'm still experiencing the same issue of it not recording the selections correctly.

Comment: Uploaded my solution to [github](https://github.com/SeToBr/ComboBoxBinding). There, after I have selected an answer in the combo box, I can change the question or question set and the answer keeps its previous selection. Can you try this?

Comment: After comparing our code in word, the mistake was a simple one - My ComboData Id values were the same, always 1. Thank you